# PHP Regex containing its limiters as ocurrences

Tags: php, regex, expression

I have this string:

```
{include="folder/file" vars="key:value"}
```

I have a regex to catch the file and the vars like this:

```
|\{include\=[\'\"](.*)\/(.*)[\'\"](.*)\}|U

First (.*) = folder
Second (.*) = file
Third (.*) = params (and I have some functions to parse it)
```

But there are some cases where I need to catch the params where they contains brackets {}. Like this:

```
{include="file" vars="key:{value}"}
```

The regext is working but it catches the results only until the first closing bracket. Like this:

```
{include="file" vars="key:{value}
```

So some part of the code remains out.

How can I make to allow those brackets as part of the results instead as a closing limiter???

Thanks!

Comment: Your last match is for `(.*)` anything, but ungreedy; and terminates at the earliest possible point. It doesn't assert the `vars=` nor quoted parts.

Comment: Yes, I know. There are some cases where that third match will have only a string, other cases where it will have a param with key/value (like in the example) but in any of those, it could contain a {value} (with brackets) so I need the regex allow the brackets inside the third match

Comment: The primary complication you introduced is trying to split up `folder/file` in that one regex. Instead repeat optionalized `(\w+)="([^"]+)"(?:\h|\})` to first split your key-value pairs up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
\{include=['"](?:(.*)\/(.*?)|(\w+))['"] vars="(.*?)"\}
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sK1qM2/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [10-16] `folder`
2.  [17-21] `file`
4.  [29-38] `key:value`
MATCH 2
3.  [51-55] `file`
4.  [63-74] `key:{value}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind what @naomik said, I think I should change my regex.
What I want to make now is detecting this structure:

```
{word="value" word="value" ... n times}
```

I have this regex: `(\w+)=['"](.*?)['"]`

it detects :

```
{include="folder/file"}
{include="folder/file" vars="key:value"}
{vars="key:{value}" include="folder/file"}  (order changed)
```

it works fine BUT I dont know how to add the initial and final brackets to the regex. When I add them it doesnt work like I want anymore

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sU9hR9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Another robust regexp that covers your first question :

```
preg_match_all("{include=[\"']{1}([^\"']+)[\"']{1} vars=[\"']{1}([^\"]+)[\"']{1}}", $str, $matches);
```

You'll get this kind of result into $matches :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {include="folder/file" vars="key:{value}"}
            [1] => {include="folder/file" vars="key:value"}
            [2] => {include="folder/file" vars="key:value"}
            [3] => {include="file" vars="key:{value}"}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder/file
            [1] => folder/file
            [2] => folder/file
            [3] => file
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => key:{value}
            [1] => key:value
            [2] => key:value
            [3] => key:{value}
        )
)
```

you can access to what matters this way : $matches[1][0] and $matches[2][0] for the first elem, $matches[1][1] $matches[2][1] for the second, etc.

It does not store folder or file in separate results. For this, you'll have to write a sub piece of code. There is no elegant way to write a regex that is covering both include="folder/file" and include="file".

It does not support the inversion of include and vars. If you want to support this, you'll have to split your input data into chunks (line by line or text between braces) before your try to match the content with something like this :

```
preg_match_all("([\w]+)=[\"']{1}([^\"']+)[\"']{1}", $chunk, $matches);
```

then matches will contain something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => vars="key:{value}"
            [1] => include="folder/file"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => vars
            [1] => include
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => key:{value}
            [1] => folder/file
        )
)
```

Then you know that $matches[1][0] contains 'vars', you can gets vars value in $matches[2][0]. For $matches[1][1] it contais 'include', you can then get 'folder/file' in $matches[2][1].